# Shortcut Ctrl + / not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 several months ago. I configured my keyboard with Belgian layout, everything was working as expected except the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. At that time I decided to surround this problem just by changing the shortcut in different tools that I am using.

But now I would like to fix this problem. But I don't know how since the keyboard layout is correct. I don't know why when I pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> tools cannot catch it.

Comment: I have two / on my keyboard. One in QWERTY pad and one in numpad. With which you are trying to configure? And what Ctrl+/ supposed to do?

Comment: I do not have numpad thus I only have one `/`

Comment: What kind of shortcut you are trying to define? And how?

Comment: Well I simply try to use the shortcut ctrl + / which is the common shortcut define by default to comment code

Comment: But that's application specific I guess

Comment: I am not sure about that since on every app I have this problem (Jetbrain suite, vsCode, jupyter,...)

Comment: So what shortcut you trying to define with this key combination?

Comment: well just to use the default behaviour generally associated to this command which is comment/uncomment code